# What are the normal subgroups of symmetric groups?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, set-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

Let's for any cardinal $\alpha$ define $S_\alpha$ as the group of all permutations of a set of cardinality $\alpha$.

Is there some sort of classification of normal subgroups of $S_\alpha$?

For $\alpha < \aleph_0$ it is well known: they are $E$, $A_\alpha$ and itself (and also $C_2 \times C_2$ in the special case when $\alpha = 4$)

However, what is for $\alpha \geq \aleph_0$?

Here we have the following subgroups, that are obviously normal:

1)For any cardinal $\beta$, such that $\aleph_0 \leq \beta \leq \alpha$, we have the subgroup $S_\alpha^{\leq \beta}$ of all permutations with the cardinality of their support $\beta$ or less.

2)For any cardinal $\beta$, such that $\aleph_0 \leq \beta \leq \alpha$, we have the subgroup $S_\alpha^{< \beta}$ of all permutations with the cardinality of their support strictly less than $\beta$.

3)The subgroup $A_\alpha$ of all permutations, that are equal to a product of even number of transpositions

4)The trivial subgroup

My question is: is there anything else? And if there is, then what?

Comment: I'd call $S_\alpha^{\leq \beta}$ those with support $\leq \beta$ and $S_\alpha^{<\beta}$ those with support $<\beta$. For $\beta$ a limit cardinal, these two differ. Also, $FS_\alpha$ is just $S_\alpha^{< \aleph_0}$ in this notation.

Comment: @lisyarus, your notation indeed makes more sense than my... I edited the question to adopt it.